# Apache 2.4 mod_geoip DENY?

Tags: apache

This is my httpd.conf, as I followed step by step the readme file.

```
<IfModule geoip_module>
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPEnableUTF8 On
GeoIPOutput Env
GeoIPScanProxyHeaders On
GeoIPDBFile GeoIP.dat
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE CN BlockCountry
Deny from env=BlockCountry
</IfModule>
```

I get this when I start apache2.4

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 560 of httpd.conf: deny not allowed here (Deny from env=BlockCountry)
```

What now? How do I deny access to the WHOLE server (not by vhosts/htaccess please)? Would be great if someday someone could write a proper readme/install procedure...
cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Deny`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#deny) directive is only valid in directory and htaccess context. It's not valid in server context.

Putting it into directory context is easy, though:

```
<Directory />
    Deny from env=BlockCountry
</Directory>
```